# Where can I set the useragent in Strawberry Perl's config?

Tags: perl

We have a proxy server here and all internet traffic is going through that. The command: *cpan package* fails with the following error:

```
LWP failed with code[403] message[Browserblocked]
```

I think, only specific browsers are let through the proxy server, so I need to set the useragent for cpan. Where can I set it? I don't see anything similar in **o conf**.

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting the code of site\lib\LWP\UserAgent.pm

```
sub _agent { "libwww-perl/$VERSION" }
```

say to:

```
sub _agent { 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:64.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/64.0' }
```

solves the problem, but is this really the official solution?

Comment: Possibly that should go into `CPAN::LWP::UserAgent`? Or that should be updated to call `LWP::UserAgent->agent` as that's the correct way to set it